# select all rows from multiple db files - php sqlite3

Tags: php, sqlite

I have multiple db files which contains the same table with different values.

example files:

> wifi_16-09-02_09_34_03.db
>
> wifi_16-09-02_09_44_06.db
>
> wifi_16-09-02_09_60_02.db

How can I select all the rows from multiple files?

I only know to do this with one file.

Here is my code:

```
  $dbfile = 'wifi_16-09-02_09_34_03.db';
  $db = new SQLite3('dbs/'.$dbfile);
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM wifi';
  $results = $db->query($sql);
```

I am new on `SQLite3`, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply open the other databases in the same way.

If you want to have all rows in a single query, you need to [attach](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) all the other databases to some main database, and use a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
$db->exec("ATTACH 'dbs/wifi_16-09-02_09_44_06.db' AS db2");
$db->exec("ATTACH 'dbs/wifi_16-09-02_09_60_02.db' AS db3");
...
$sql = <<<'SQL'
    SELECT * FROM main.wifi
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM db2.wifi
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM db3.wifi
SQL;
$results = $db->query($sql);
```

Comment: I am getting an error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in`

Comment: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: db2.wifi'` but all databases have the same table. can you help me?

Comment: Apparently, there is no table named `db2.wifi'`.

Comment: I believe there is. Whatever file I use in ATTACH it is showing the error. If I use the file in main, there is no error.

Comment: I posted a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342752/php-sqlite-attach-no-such-table-exception

Comment: If you do it like this it won't work. You need to specifie full path to database file. Ex: ATTACH 'C:\databases\wifi.db' AS db2