# PHP SQLite ATTACH “no such table” exception

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to attach multiple database files and select from them. All database files have the same one table, just different values.

Here is my method:

```
try {
$file_db = new PDO('sqlite:dbs/wifi_16-09-01_10_03_01.db');

$file_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
                        PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$file_db->exec("ATTACH DATABASE 'wifi_16-09-02_09_44_06.db' AS db2");

$result = $file_db->query('SELECT * FROM main.wifi UNION ALL SELECT * FROM db2.wifi');

$file_db = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

and the error is

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: db2.wifi

how can I fix this?

if there is a better solution, I will use it.

Comment: Are you sure that you can put a line break into a plain string?

Comment: yes if you are referring to query string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I have researched few hours. I finally found a solution.

Give full path of attached database, like:

```
$file_db->exec("ATTACH DATABASE 'C:/Users/name/folder/Projects/htdocs/p1/dbs/yourdbfile.db' AS db2");
```

In my case I did not give any path, and it was generating db files under XAMPP folder.